# What is the origin of the phrase "SaaS"?

Tags: web-applications, web-services, software-as-a-service

Recently I heard someone say they built a "SaaS" application.  At first I thought "this guy knows something new", and I figured SaaS was some hyped enterprise framework or design pattern, but after looking up the [SaaS Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) I realized it's similar in meaning to "web app".

What is the origin of the phrase "SaaS"?  When was it first used?

Answer (score 5):

The term replaces Application Service Provider and can be found in documents dating back to at least [early 2001](http://www.siia.net/estore/ssb-01.pdf).

> Software as a Service (SaaS), commonly referred to as the Application
>   Service Provider (ASP) model, is  heralded by many as the new wave in
>   application software distribution. Following the maxim that “the 
>   Internet changes everything,” many believe that traditional packaged
>   desktop and enterprise applications will  soon be swept away by the
>   tide of Web-based, outsourced products and services that remove the 
>   responsibility for installation, maintenance and upgrades from
>   over-burdened MIS staff. Some analysts and  industry members believe
>   that packaged software, as a separate entity will cease to exist.
>   While such drastic  predictions have not yet happened, due to
>   technical and business issues, the spirit of this change – the 
>   delivery, management and payment of software as a service rather than
>   a product – is affecting all participants  in the software industry

It appears that the term was non-existent or not widely used before that point. An article from [April of 2000](http://www.destinationcrm.com/Articles/Editorial/Magazine-Features/ASP-and-Ye-Shall-Receive-41700.aspx) uses ASP.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/SaaS:

> The term "SaaS" was coined by John Koenig for the SDForum Software as a Service Conference in March of 2005 and has become the industry adopted reference term, generally replacing the earlier terms "On-Demand" and "ASP" (Application Service Provider).

Comment: Wow, so many new phrases to add to my resume.  I will be very popular with HR departments.